# ANGULAR. How to Create API routes or endpoints using den1.mssql7.gear.host backend database

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm a newbie and not good in explanation can you please help me in ANGULAR?. How to Create API routes or endpoints using den1.mssql7.gear.host backend database. Example, like this code  return this.http.get(`${this.url}/order/all`)

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  // apiBaseUrl: 'http://api.amseljewelry.us/api',
}
```

Example, in this function below

```
getAllData: callback => {
        connection.query(
            `select * from view_order ORDER BY order_id asc`,
            (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    return callback(error);
                }
                return callback(null, result);
            }
        )
    }
```

Now, how to convert it to API endpoints. I created a Service and the code looks like this

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class OrderServiceService {
  url = `${environment.apiBaseUrl}`;
  tableArry: any[]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getAllData(){  //view_order
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/order/all`);
```

}

```
}
```

Comment: You have almost made it. Put the `getAllData` function in the service, and it is done. Just don't forget to import/create the `connection` variable.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to make that function `getAllData()`  as API Web routes and become like this return this.http.get(`${this.url}/order/all`)  ....

Comment: host: den1.mssql7.gear.host
user: a****
pass: Rv****

..........how to access the backend database.. and create API endpoints or routes and become like this http://api.amseljewelry.us/api